# JPA Entity not updating until server restart

Tags: java, jpa

I have a ternary relationship in my database: User, Book and BookOrder.
The JPA entities are defined like this:

```
class Book {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "book")
    private Collection<BookOrder> bookOrderCollection;
    ....
}

class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "reader")
    private Collection<BookOrder> bookOrderCollection;
    ....
}

class BookOrder {
    @JoinColumn(name = "BOOK_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    @ManyToOne
    private Book book;

    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "READER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    @ManyToOne
    private User reader;
    ....
}
```

When I want to save, I just do this:

```
Book book = ...;
User reader = ...;
BookOrder order = new BookOrder();
order.setBook(book);
order.setReader(reader);
book.getBookOrderCollection().add(order);
reader.getBookOrderCollection().add(order);
book.setQuantity(book.getQuantity() - 1);
bookFacade.edit(book);
```

And BookFacade class is:

```
class BookFacade {
    public void create(Book entity) {
        getEntityManager().persist(entity);
        getEntityManager().flush();
    }

    public void edit(Book entity) {
        getEntityManager().merge(entity);
    }

    public void remove(Book entity) {
        getEntityManager().remove(getEntityManager().merge(entity));
    }

    public Book find(Object id) {
        return getEntityManager().find(Book.class, id);
    }
}
```

That works fine in that the book quantity is updated in the database and the `BookOrder` is inserted.  However, the `User`'s `bookOrderCollection` is not updated until the server is restarted (when I pull the reader from the database).

I want to avoid performing `usersFacade.edit(reader)` because it not safe to create two transactions for one operation.  Instead, I added `cascade = Cascade.ALL` to the `reader` field in `Order` class, but it didn't solve the problem.

How can I make it work within one transaction?

Comment: What is the entity BookOrder ?

Comment: How are delimited your transactions ?

Comment: BookOrder is an entity that presents order of book. It have the book the orderd, the reader, and other fields like: address, price, etc.

Comment: @JohnBollinger if more information is needed just tell me

Comment: We cannot definitively answer the question as posed, because you have not provided all needed information.  In particular, we normally want to see a [mcve].  A true MCVE may be difficult to provide in this case, but the details of your persistence context configuration and of the implementation of `BookFacade` are relevant.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I have added the `BookFacade` implementation. Is there other information missing?

Comment: With that said, I can *speculate* that your `Reader` is not being updated because it has become detached as a result of having been obtained from a transaction-scoped persistence context and that context's transaction having completed.

Comment: Nothing you have presented shows how your transaction boundaries are demarcated, nor whether your persistence contexts are transaction-scoped or extended.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I mistakenly wrote a different class name. Instead of `Order` it should be `BookOrder` (I have updated the question). Is that missing part of information? I have no more code (but there are more fields in the classes but they are irrelevant for the relationship). Please tell me if you need more information.

Comment: @nrofis, I suspected you had provided the wrong class name, but that is not the information I already said was missing.  How are your transaction boundaries demarcated? Are you using transaction-scoped persistence contexts or extended ones?

Comment: As @JohnBollinger already said before, I think it is best for you to put real example somewhere (github?). Just my guess: I think you generated your application using netbeans generator? If so, then, is it JSF application? If all my guess correct, then

`How can I make it work within one transaction?`

Then delegate your `xxxFacade` with another facade (I guess it is EJB beans) and use proper `@Transactional` annotation to eliminate your statement that, `.... I want to avoid performing usersFacade.edit(reader) because it not safe to create two transactions for one operation....`

Comment: @JohnBollinger `PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION`

Comment: How are you checking that the reader's collection hasn't been updated?  Could you have cached an instance of it somewhere instead of reading it from a context after the transaction has committed?

Comment: When I pull the same reader again from the database, the `bookOrderCollection`'s size stay the same until the server restart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "book")` is the inverse relation, not the direct one. Maybe adding `CASCADE` to the other side (`@ManyToOne`) of the relation would have a different effect.

Comment: The suggestion is an answer though, as by adding cascade merge, the changes to the book and User will be picked up and synchronized to the database.  Without cascade merge, JPA only sees the changes to the bookOrder, not the changes to the Book and Order's bookOrder collections.  While the database will be updated, the Book and Order entities in the cache will not, and their collections will not show the change until they are refreshed or the cache is cleared

Comment: @Chris, there is a difference between "leads to solving the problem" and "is an answer to the question".  This answer may be the former, but it is not the latter.  If your comments were part of the answer then it would be more convincing as an answer.